# Google play java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-play

I have an app with 100 installs done but I have 2 error on `java.lang.NullPointerException`; the thing is that when that error came in my device or emulator I could solve it, but I want to ask if there are any way to repair that error if you don't know in which part it crashes?

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{espanolasguapas/espanolasguapas.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1750)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1766)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at espanolasguapas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1714)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you reproduce the error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sxa.sexolia.espanolasguapas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace tells you which line had the null pointer:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at sxa.sexolia.espanolasguapas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
```

Your issue is on **line 119** of `MainActivity.java`.

Make sure you look at the code you used when you released the product - it's possible your development branch has changed since you last released your code, which would mess up the line numbers.